# The divergent sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (n^2)! x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series, regularization

#### Question

I'm interested in assigning a value to the divergent series $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (n^2)! x^n$. I'm hoping that **(1)** the definition for $F(x)$ has (one-sided) derivatives of $(-1)^n (n^2)!$ at 0. There are many functions with exactly the same derivatives at $0$, so I want $F(x)$ to be **(2)** formally connected to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (n^2)! x^n$ through some equation.

**(2)** is fairly vague, since I don't know the right condition. Thus, I'll give a few examples of what I mean. The series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! x^n$ formally solves the differential equation $x \frac{d}{dx} (xf(x)) = f(x)-1$, so this differential equation formally characterizes the behavior the assignment must have. Likewise, the equation $2x f(2^2 x) = f(x)-1$ is formally solved by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{n^2} x^n$.

The assignment $f(x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x} \operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), x<0$ for the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! x^n$ is the type of thing I'm looking for. $f(x)$ solves the differential equation mentioned before, and also has nth derivatives (taken from the left) equal to $n!$

#### Attempt

So far, I have considered these two similar approaches, which (numerically) appear to lead to the same function.

Let
$\vartheta(w,x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n w^{n^2}x^n$. This series converges for $|w|<1$ and cannot be analytically continued by the gap theorem. However, we can define an extension for real $w>1$ and $x>0$. Let $$\vartheta(w,x) = 1+\frac{1}{2i}\int_C w^{z^2} x^z \csc(\pi z)dz$$
Where $C$ is the contour that goes from $c + \sqrt{-i}\infty$ to $c$ to $c + \sqrt{i}\infty$, with $0<c<1$

We can sum the series using the Borel transform and the extension for $\vartheta$ as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (n^2)! x^n= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{n^2}x^ndt = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} (\vartheta(t,x)-1) dt$$

A second approach more directly uses residues to write
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (n^2)! x^n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{1/2 - i \infty}^{1/2 + i \infty} x^z \Gamma(z^2+1) \Gamma(z+1)\Gamma(-z) dz$$

Both methods appear to obtain the same function (but this might just be an artifact of them being almost identical methods). Moreover, numerically, they appear to have derivatives $(-1)^n (n^2)!$ at zero, though I could numerically test this only up to $n=2$ (when $n=3$ the derivative is already $-362880$).

Using the second residue approach, one can find a functional equation that the series satisfies, which is
$$F(x)+F(1/x) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ \sqrt{n} \cos(\sqrt{n} \ln(x)) \operatorname{csch}(\pi \sqrt{n}) }{n!}$$
Though I cannot see any argument that suggests $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (n^2)! x^n$ should formally satisfy this equation, so this does not appear useful.

Comment: One idea is to consider the series 

$$ g(s,x) =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  e^{n! s} x^n $$  

So $ \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s^2} [0, x] $ is the function you seek. 


So the function $g$ is clearly defined for all $x$ if $s \le 0$ but defining it else where will probably be a little tricky.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal That is an interesting idea-- but I think the series diverges too quickly for that method to work. If we try to look at the limit as $s \to 0^-$, then if $x>0$, the limit of the derivatives will be infinite. If $x<0$ I think $g(s,x)$ will be oscillating between arbitrarily large numbers, so the limit won't exist. I think the idea is that $e^{n! s}$ decays way too fast-- its basically either $1$ or $0$, so there's no way it can cause the $(n^2)!$ terms to reasonably cancel.